# Ignorecase in awk creates unintentional output

Tags: awk, gsub, ignore-case

I'm pretty new to scripting (2 months) and have run into an issue using Ignorecase in awk which I don't understand. I have a solution already in using sed but I'd still like to know why the below has occurred and how to avoid it.

From this line;

`echo foo.BAZ.bar | awk 'IGNORECASE = 1;{gsub(/'.baz.'/,"'.'")};{print}'`

I get the output,

`foo.BAZ.bar
foo.bar`

but I expect the output `foo.bar` only. The behaviour above can be avoided by removing `IGNORECASE = 1;` from the line, but this then means that `.BAZ.`, will of course, not be removed from `foo.BAZ.bar`. This behaviour seems odd to me and very undesirable!

Thanks for any input it's greatly appreciated :)

Vince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:

```
echo foo.BAZ.bar | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}{gsub(/[.]baz[.]/,".")}1'
```

When you put an explicit `;` after the `IGNORECASE` statement, your line gets printed as is before any modification, since the action is returned true and `awk` prints the line. Once `gsub` gets to modify the line, the explicit `print` then prints the modified line.

Also, notice the way, strings are kept in `gsub` function.

Update: As stated in the comments by Ed, using the previous solution would test the IGNORECASE variable against every line. Putting it in BEGIN section assigns it once and uses it for entire file.

Comment: Thanks Jay, this is the information I needed. I can see why the ; causes this behaviour now :)

Comment: That's the wrong approach. You don't want to test the results of assigning 1 to a variable for every line in your input file. See @Kent's solution or move the assignment to the BEGIN section. Also what you have as the first arg in gsub() is not a string, it's a regexp so `.`, for example does not mean the character `.`, it means any single character. It's important to always be aware of the distinction between strings and regexps so it doesn't bite you when you least expect it.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback as always @EdMorton. I have updated to solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  echo foo.BAZ.bar|awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '{gsub(/.baz./,".")}7'      
foo.bar
```